# Gzip compress/uncompress a long char array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, gzip, crypto++

I need to compress a large byte array, im already using the Crypto++ library in the application, so having the compression/decompression part in the same library would be great.

this little test works as expected:

```
///
string test = "bleachbleachtestingbiatchbleach123123bleachbleachtestingb.....more";
string compress(string input)
{
    string result ("");
    CryptoPP::StringSource(input, true, new CryptoPP::Gzip(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result), 1));
    return result;
}

string decompress(string _input)
{
    string _result ("");
    CryptoPP::StringSource(_input, true, new CryptoPP::Gunzip(new CryptoPP::StringSink(_result), 1));
    return _result;
}

void main()
{
    string compressed = compress(test);
    string decompressed = decompress(compressed);
    cout << "orginal size :" << test.length() << endl;
    cout << "compressed size :" << compressed.length() << endl;
    cout << "decompressed size :" << decompressed.length() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I need to compress something like this:

```
unsigned char long_array[194506]
{
  0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,
  0x01,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x00,0x04,
  0x04,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x02,0x00,0x04,
  0x01,0x00,0x02,0x02,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x00,0x00,
  0x03,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x01,0x00,0x04,
  ....
};
```

i tried to use the long_array as const char * and as byte then feed it to the compress function, it seems to be compressed but the decompressed one has a size of 4, and its clearly uncomplete. maybe its too long.
How could i rewrite those compress/uncompress functions to work with that byte array?
Thank you all. :)

Comment: Perhaps `compress()` stops at the first NULL byte it sees, given that it doesn't take an argument to explicitly specify the length of the data to be compressed. If that is the case, there's probably a different function you need to use for compressing arbitrary binary data. I'm not overly familiar with Crypto++, though...

Comment: yes it stops after the first null byte. I cant manage to find a documentation/snipped to work with byte arrays.

Comment: The Crypto++ wiki now has a page for Gzip, including a patch that allows you to read and write the modified file time, the original filename and comments. See [Gzip](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gzip) wiki page.

Answer (score 3):

> i tried to use the array as const char * and as byte then feed it to the compress function, it seems to be compressed but the decompressed one has a size of 4, and its clearly uncomplete.

Use the alternate `StringSource` constructor that takes a [pointer and a length](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_string_source.html). It will be immune to embedded `NULL's`.

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(long_array, sizeof(long_array), true,
    new CryptoPP::Gzip(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(result), 1)
));
```

Or, you can use:

```
Gzip zipper(new StringSink(result), 1);
zipper.Put(long_array, sizeof(long_array));
zipper.MessageEnd();
```

Crypto++ added an [`ArraySource`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySource) at 5.6. You can use it too (but its really a `typedef` for a `StringSource`):

```
CryptoPP::ArraySource as(long_array, sizeof(long_array), true,
    new CryptoPP::Gzip(
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(result), 1)
));
```

The `1` that is used as an argument to `Gzip` is a deflate level. `1` is one of the lowest compressions. You might consider using `9` or `Gzip::MAX_DEFLATE_LEVEL` (which is 9). The default log<sub>2</sub> windows size is the max size, so there's no need to turn any knobs on it.

```
Gzip zipper(new StringSink(result), Gzip::MAX_DEFLATE_LEVEL);
```

You should also name your declarations. I've seen GCC generate bad code when using anonymous declarations.

Finally,  use `long_array` (or similar) because `array` is a keyword in C++ 11.